# What approach should i take to find unique number

Tags: mysql, node.js, architecture, google-cloud-firestore, projects-and-solutions

After discussing with entire the team we did not get the solution yet now. What is the scenario?

1. 100k users enter a number (it can be whatever number) by the mobile application, Server can have 80k to 100k request at the same time.
2. Once the user enters the number and if the number found unique and minimum over the 100k user's input, that time all user should be notified that X user's number was unique
3. Also, want to find duplicate numbers and notify them for their bad luck.

All above point **1,2,3** operation should take 2 seconds max to max

What our approach is so far.

1. For the storage, We thought firestore would be the best choice. But reading count will be increased and that will be a huge effect on the billing. Also, we perform some operation with the testing account but it is taking more than 4 seconds to complete our requirements with 1K numbers only.
2. According to the point **2**. above, We thought to use cloud function which is the best choice, Mobile developers only need to call a cloud function and store data wherever we wanted to insert. And for the unique and minimum number, the mobile side has a listener.

Where we are stuck.

1. Firestore is no more helpful for us so we thought to use MySQL of cloud SQL but it has also the limitation of concurrent user connection.

Right now we are using Nodejs for cloud functions.

I am waiting for the guidance if there is any another idea which is away from our thoughts.